# Alternate sentence for I reached home

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, phrase-usage

I saw a creepy man coming towards me I start running straight to my home. After "i reached home" I locked all the doors and windows. In this para what alternative word can I use instead of "I reached home".

Comment: after I got home...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not accept writing requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come, I arrived, I came...

Comment: I've heard something like "when I made it home".I'm not sure what exactly I heard in that story but that was something like this. If you know then please let me know

Comment: Yes sure, you can say that!

Comment: Please accept my answer if you’re satisfied with it!

Comment: Please remember that when writing answers on StackExchange, [“brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better”](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). To make this a good answer, you should explain _why_ your options are superior to the ones in the question, and preferably also add in links to some reliable, authoritative sources that show that these suggestions are in fact appropriate and used. (To wit, the first option you list is _not_ appropriate: “After I have come home I locked all the doors” is ungrammatical due to tense mismatch.)

Comment: The first one would be ungrammatical in OP’s sentence and the other two aren’t really suitable for when you’re racing home for sanctuary.